# Page-navigation using stored procedure (can not bind a composite identifier)

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, data-paging

I am using a stored procedure to make page-navigation when I view a list of stores. I have only one table `Store` with columns `Name` & `S_Id`.

And here is my query :

```
    SELECT  Stores.Name
    FROM
       (
         SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Stores.S_Id) AS rownum ,
            Stores.Name
         FROM Stores    
       )AS ordered
    WHERE ordered.rownum BETWEEN [someValue] AND [someValue]
```

But when I try to save my procedure I get an error:

> can not bind a composite identifier Stores.Name

I have seen a lot of topics but cant find whats wrong. If I doing it with LINQ I will try something like this :

```
    (select name from Stores order by S_Id).Skip(n).Take(m) .
```

Comment: What tool / program is sending that exact error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subquery defines a new name - `ordered` - for your data - so you need to use that new name instead of `stores`:

```
SELECT  
    ordered.Name    <=== you're selecting from the subquery which is called "ordered" - use that name!!
FROM
   (SELECT 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Stores.S_Id) AS rownum,
       Stores.Name
    FROM Stores    
   ) AS ordered
WHERE 
   ordered.rownum BETWEEN [someValue] AND [someValue]
```